# Aplicacion Shiny de R funciona en Rstudio pero no desde linea de comandos, se queda en listening on http

Tags: r, shiny

tengo una aplicación shiny en R que se ejecuta correctamente desde Rstudio tanto si lo hago con "run in window", como "run external" y se muestra todo correctamente. El problema es la quiero ejecutar desde linea de comandos para compartirla con otra persona. Para ello, he creado una carpeta con R, para hacerlo portable y con una versión de Chrome portable.
Al ejecutarlo de ese modo, empieza la ejecución, carga los datos, pero abre el explorador y se queda pensando siempre con el mensaje "Listening on [http://127.0.0.1:XXXX"](http://127.0.0.1:XXXX%22) donde XXXX es un puerto que va cambiando, ya que no lo he fijado.
He actualizado todas las librerías de R, como he visto por algún foro, e incluso he probado de poner como aplicación solamente que muestre el "hola mundo" tomada de internet con el mismo resultado, por lo que no creo que sea problema de la aplicación, esta aplicación de prueba es:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  "Hello, world!"
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Para ejecutarlo desde el portable, primero ejecuto un archivo punto bat:

```
SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole

R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe %ROPTS% runShinyApp.R 1> ShinyApp.log 2>&1
```

Y el script que carga para cargar la aplicación es (lo tomé de un ejemplo de internet):

```
    message('library paths:\n', paste('... ', .libPaths(), sep='', collapse='\n')) 
    launch.browser = function(appUrl) {
         shell(sprintf('"%s" --app=%s', 
                    file.path(getwd(),
                               'GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe'), 
                      appUrl)) 
} 
shiny::runApp('./shiny/app.R', launch.browser=launch.browser)
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede suceder? No aparece ningún otro error, se queda en listening y parece que se ejecuta todo, pero no carga nada y si pones la dirección en otro explorador tampoco y el problema es que no funciona ni la de hola mundo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo. El problema parece que se encuentra con el Chrome portable ya que se abre la ventana del Chrome pero no llega a aparecer nada.

Si cambio el valor a launch.browswer = TRUE lanza el explorador por defecto y me funciona sin problemas.

De todos modos, si alguien sabe por que hay ese problema con el Chrome portable me gustaría saberlo para poder incluir el propio navegador aunque de momento utilizaré el navegador por defecto del equipo